# What is the value referred to when we assign the setTimeout function to a variable?

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

Hi when I assign the simple setTimeOut() function to a variable and console the variable, it produces some integer value as below:

[image]

So, I want clarification on what the value denotes. The value is changing when I try the same again. So please provide me an explanation of the value we get while assigning the setTimeOut() to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` function returns a unique id with which you can stop your `setTimeout` like this `clearTimeout(timeoutID)`.
It’s the same with `setInterval`.

[See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout) here.

Greetings, Flo

Answer (score 0):

The function [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) returns an identifier that you can use to prevent the execution of the function by calling [clearTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It is id returned from setTimeout() which used to clear the timeout

```
myTimeout = setTimeout(function, milliseconds);
clearTimeout(myTimeout);
```

[For More Informtion Please Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)